# Access meta site from main and vice versa from left bar

Tags: feature-request, left-navigation

I'm often annoyed to be forced to go through my profile to switch between meta and main site.

I think the new left bar shows an opportunity to create a more convenient shortcut.

My best designers skills can do no better than that :

[image: meta navigation added to new left navigation]

Comment: You do not need to go through your profile. Check the menu in the upper right.

Comment: Now I'm happy, a red circle made by hand.... good job...